# How to handle a click evet for multiple DIVs in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a situation where I have multiple DIVs that require a click event listener, just like a CSS accordion or memory match game (each tile responding to a click event).

I can do this with JavaScript like, so:

```
const accordionHeaders = document.querySelectorAll(".panel-header");

accordionHeaders.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener("click", event => {
       // code
  });
});
```

How can I mimic the same functionality using React hooks? I did it for one item, like so:

```
  const [isOpen, setState] = useState(false);
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(0);
  const ref = useRef(null);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setState(!isOpen);
    (ref.current.nextElementSibling.clientHeight) ? setHeight(0) : setHeight(ref.current.nextElementSibling.scrollHeight + "px");
  }
```

and it works, but each item in the accordion has a different scrollHeight, depending on which one is clicked. I would be grateful for any suggestion. Thank you!

Comment: Do you want an accordion? I would look for something ready. It might makes sense for your project to have a full ui library, if not, you can also look for something specific like https://github.com/springload/react-accessible-accordion.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are building the individual divs with a for loop or a `.map()`, so when building the divs (tiles), you can assign onClick method for each one with a different parameter.

```
renderList() {
    let divDOM = []

    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.data.length; i++) {
        divDOM.push(
            <div onClick={() => this.moreInfo(i)}>
                Div {i}
            </div>
        );
    }

    return divDOM;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Can the keyword "this" be used with hooks as well?

Comment: I can also get acces to the clicked element with "event.target" but I don't know how to toggle a class for each one separately.

Comment: I am using refs in order to toggle in-built classes. In the function moreInfo for example you can:
`let targetElement = this.divRef.current.children.namedItem(i);`
- on each div: id={i} key={i}